# Hadoop Hive Query: Multi-join

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How can I do sub-selections in Hive? I think I might be making a really obvious mistake that's not so obvious to me...

Error I'm receiving: `FAILED: Parse Error: line 4:8 cannot recognize input 'SELECT' in expression specification`

Here are my three source tables:

```
aaa_hit -> [SESSION_KEY, HIT_KEY, URL]
aaa_event-> [SESSION_KEY,HIT_KEY,EVENT_ID]
aaa_session->[SESSION_KEY,REMOTE_ADDRESS]
```

...and what I want to do is insert the result into a result table like this:

```
result -> [url, num_url, event_id, num_event_id, remote_address, num_remote_address]
```

...where column 1 is the URL, column 3 is the top 1 "event" per URL, and column 5 is the top 1 REMOTE_ADDRESS to visit that URL. (Even columns are "count"s of the previous column.)

**Soooooo**... what did I do wrong here?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE result2
SELECT url, 
       COUNT(url) AS access_url, 
       (SELECT events.event_id as evt, 
               COUNT(events.event_id) as access_evt
        FROM   aaa_event events 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN aaa_hit hits 
                 ON ( events.hit_key = hit_key )
                 ORDER BY access_evt DESC LIMIT 1), 
       (SELECT sessions.remote_address as remote_address, 
               COUNT(sessions.remote_address) as access_addr
        FROM   aaa_session sessions 
               RIGHT OUTER JOIN aaa_hit hits 
                 ON ( sessions.session_key = session_key )
                 ORDER BY access_addr DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM   aaa_hit
ORDER  BY access_url DESC;
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: What error is hive giving you? Hive gives a fairly useful error and the exact position in the query that's causing it's problem. That should allow you to look at the exact spot in the query that's causing problems, or so we can.

Comment: Good point. I'm getting an error at 4:8, or the beginning of the first sub-SELECT statement. More specifically: `FAILED: Parse Error: line 4:8 cannot recognize input 'SELECT' in expression specification`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries

> Hive supports subqueries only in the
>   FROM clause.

You can't use a subquery as a 'column' in Hive.

To work around this you'll want to use that subquery in a FROM clause and `JOIN` to it. (the below won't work, but is the idea)

```
SELECT url, 
       COUNT(url) AS access_url, 
       t2.col1, t2.col2 ...
FROM   aaa_hit
JOIN (SELECT events.event_id as evt, 
               COUNT(events.event_id) as access_evt
        FROM   aaa_event events 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN aaa_hit hits 
                 ON ( events.hit_key = hit_key )
                 ORDER BY access_evt DESC LIMIT 1), 
       (SELECT sessions.remote_address as remote_address, 
               COUNT(sessions.remote_address) as access_addr
        FROM   aaa_session sessions 
               RIGHT OUTER JOIN aaa_hit hits 
                 ON ( sessions.session_key = session_key )
                 ORDER BY access_addr DESC LIMIT 1) t2
ON (aaa_hit.THING = t2.THING)
```

Check out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins for more information on using JOINs in Hive.

Comment: So do I have to make another table, then?

Comment: Good to know I can't do this, but how should I get around it?

Comment: @Travis Powell: added details

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a GroupBy operation, Count is an aggregation. Only count(*) works without a GroupBy clause.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+GroupBy

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)